# How to fix this problem discord.py bot problem

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I created a bot in discord.py which works perfectly before i add a block of code. Once i added the code it stops working. Then i removed the newly added code. But my bot is not working now  and sometimes it sends reply after 5 minutes but it doesn't shows any error. Then i created a new bot and pasted the token to check whether there is any problem with my code but it works perfectly.

i am wondering what is the problem bcs it didn't show any error  and even with token as it prints in terminal too and even it sends reply to commands sometimes after 5 minutes. I regenerated the token of my bot even but now too the same problem is there.

Can someone say how to make my old bot to work properly? I don't want to start with new bot since my old bot is already in 86 servers and struggled hard to join it in that much servers.

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import discord
from random import randint 
import keep_alive
import DiscordUtils
import random
from discord_components import *
# intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True,members=True,typing=True,presences=True)
bot = Bot(command_prefix="?", case_insensitive=True,intents=intents)
bot.remove_command("help")
global music
music = DiscordUtils.Music()
DiscordComponents(bot)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game(f'on {len(bot.guilds)} servers | ?help'))
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user}")




@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        title_error_one = 'You have not entered anything after the command'
        desc_error_one = 'Use **?help** to see a list of all the commands available'
        embed_var_one = discord.Embed(title=title_error_one,
                                      description=desc_error_one,
                                      colour=randint(0, 0xffffff))
        await ctx.reply(embed=embed_var_one)
    if isinstance(error, commands.MaxConcurrencyReached):
        title_error_four = 'Someone is already playing'
        desc_error_four = 'Please wait until the person currently playing is done with their turn'
        embed_var_four = discord.Embed(title=title_error_four,
                                       description=desc_error_four,
                                       colour=randint(0, 0xffffff))
        await ctx.reply(embed=embed_var_four)
    if isinstance(error,commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        embed = discord.Embed(
              title="**Still on Cooldown!**",
              description=f"Try again in {error.retry_after:.2f}s.",
              colour=randint(0, 0xffffff)
          )    
        await ctx.reply(embed=embed)     

    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound): 
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
          if(filename.endswith('.py')):
            bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)




keep_alive.keep_alive()
token = os.environ.get("TOKEN")
bot.run(token)
```

This is the code on main.py file
I don't think other files have any errors. I only doubt with this file.
**Thank you for help in advance**

## Atlast i found that it is due to on_member_update command.

Once i commented it. My bot works fine(: and below is my on_member_update code. Is there anything Wrong or some way to make it fast. Below is the code

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_update(self,before, after):
    try:
      serverId=after.guild.id
      channel_id=int(logs_info.find_one(
          {'id': serverId})['action_logs'])
      logchannel = self.bot.get_channel(channel_id)
    except:
      return
    IST = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
    time_now = (datetime.now(IST))
    time_now = str(time_now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    if len(before.roles) < len(after.roles):
        new_role = next(role for role in after.roles if role not in before.roles)
        embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Roles given",description=f"{after.mention} has been given {new_role.mention} role",colour=randint(0, 0xffffff))
        embed.add_field(name="Role added at",value=time_now)
    elif(len(before.roles) > len(after.roles)):
        new_role = next(role for role in before.roles if role not in after.roles)
        embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Removed",description=f"{new_role.mention} role has been removed from {after.mention}",colour=randint(0, 0xffffff))
        embed.add_field(name="Role removed at",value=time_now)
    else:
      return
    
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=after.guild.icon_url)
    embed.set_footer(text=self.bot.user.name,icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)
    embed.set_author(name=after.name, icon_url=after.avatar_url)
    await logchannel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: It seems that your issue is that the bot is slow to reply at times?

Comment: @Roopesh-J Yes before i commented this part help commands even takes 5 minutes time to send ):. Now is there anyway to make this part of code work fast

Comment: At quick glance, I don't see anything wrong with the code or ways to dramatically speed it up. I assume the bulk of the work is getting the `channel_id` from the database and two list comprehensions. But it doesn't seem like that should slow the code down that much. If anything maybe come up with a faster way to get the `channel_id`? When the member updates their profile, what channel are you trying to get? Is it the same everytime or does it differ per member and how?

Comment: @Roopesh-J It is logging command. If someone updates their profile it will send that to a specific channel that is specified by the user

Comment: Ah ok, so each user has specified a channel they want the log to be sent to. Hm, yeah in that case I have no other ideas on how to speed it up. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem explanation

You use **pymongo** library to fetch some data in your `on_member_update` event:

```py
channel_id=int(logs_info.find_one({'id': serverId})['action_logs'])
```

It's so bad because **pymongo** is a blocking library. It means that when you interact with your database this library blocks other code. Therefore your bot is so slow. It can't process command while it waits for **pymongo** request.

## Solution

You can use **[motor](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)** instead of **pymongo**. It's an asynchronous wrapper for **pymongo** and it is related to this. But **motor** doesn't block your code execution.

Comment: Then could you accept my answer, please? Use a green tick.

Comment: but motor slows everything

Comment: No, motor is the asynchronous library. It doesn’t block your code.

Comment: Yes it doesn't blocks my code rather is slows my code by 10-20s slow. When i used motor this part begin to start working but all commands begins to slow by a bit of 10-20 seconds anyway thank you for your help. That part of code works fine now but with some delay (: